# Arithmetic Combination of Two Distributions and Chernoff Bounds

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a set of i.i.d random variables $X_i$ with distribution:
\begin{align}
X\stackrel{d}{=}
\begin{cases}
\mathcal U[-z,z] & \text{ if } K_i \leq 0.5 \\
\mathcal U[-1,1] & \text{ if } K_i > 0.5
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $K_i$ are i.i.d. with distribution $\mathcal U[0,1]$ and $z>0$.

How can I combine this into one smooth distribution $f(X_i)$?

The overall aim is I want to find the pdf of $X_i^2$, so I can use Chernoff to find the probability bounds $\Pr[\sum^N_{i=0} X^2_i \geq t] \leq 3e^{\frac{-t^2}{12\mu}}$

I was thinking if it is possible to rewrite it as something like $X_i \stackrel{d}{=} \mathcal U[0,z] ; $ and then additionally $X_i\stackrel{d}{=}X_i+\mathcal U[0,1-z] ; \text{ if } K<0.333$ and then possibly using some sort of convolution.

Comment: What is $k$? Is it a random variable?

Comment: I do assume that $k$ is $U[0,1]$. However what i'm not sure of is if $k$ is chosen, and is used for all $X_i$, or if a new $k$ is chosen before each $X_i$

Comment: Sorry yes each variable has a $k_i$

Comment: I have made some major edits based on the comments. If that is not right, then you can roll it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density of $X_i$ is not smooth, but it is relatively simple

- If $0 \lt z \le 1$ then 
  $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
           \frac{1}{4z}+\frac14 & \mbox{if $-z \le x \le z$};\\
           \frac14 & \mbox{if $-1 \le x \lt -z$ or $z \lt x \le 1$}\\
           0 & \mbox{if $x \lt -1$ or $1 \lt x$}\end{array} \right.$$
- If $1 \le z$ then 
  $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
           \frac{1}{4z}+\frac14 & \mbox{if $-1 \le x \le 1$};\\
           \frac1{4z} & \mbox{if $-z \le x \lt -1$ or $1 \lt x \le z$}\\
           0 & \mbox{if $x \lt -z$ or $z \lt x$}\end{array} \right.$$

and in either case $\mathbb E\left[X\right] = 0$ and  $\mathbb E\left[X^2\right] = \frac{z^2+1}6$